# Accessing system colors in WatchKit

Tags: uikit, swiftui, watchkit

I am trying to use UIKit colors for my Apple Watch interface. You can do it in iOS with `UIColor` class properties like `.systemBackground` and others. For example:

```
let myColor = UIColor.systemBlue
```

Gives me error when compiling watchOS extension target:

> Type 'UIColor' has no member 'UIColor.systemBlue'.

I wonder tis there alternative way to get this system colors, and if not — what I need is to get a color of some UI elements, like SwiftUI table view row background which looks very similar to `UIColor.systemGray5`.

```
@State private var isActive = false

var body: some View {
  List {
    Section() {
      ForEach(self.dataSource) { item in
        CustomCell()
        .listRowPlatterColor(self.isActive ? Color(UIColor.systemGray5) : Color(.orange))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Code above won't compile because `UIColor.systemGray5` is not found in WatchKit. I have tried to create a class which is sued both in iPhone and Watch target and it fixes Xcode autocompletion. But the app breaks when trying to use it the Apple Watch target.

I hope there's a way rather then finding correct color and hard-coding it.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation, the UIColor.system-ish are only available for iOS, Catalyst and some for tvOS. What you can do is extend UIColor and create you systemGray5:

```
extension UIColor {
    static var mySystemGray5: UIColor {
        return .init(red: 229/255, green: 229/255, blue: 234/255, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

And use on your code like:

```
  ForEach(self.dataSource) { item in
    CustomCell()
    .listRowPlatterColor(self.isActive ? Color(UIColor.mySystemGray5) : Color(.orange))
  }
```

Comment: I agree, UIColor are available only for iOS. There isn't difference for watchOS between *light* and dark mode, as an alternative to an extension, you can also add a single color in Assets.xcassets

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using SwiftUI, `Color.blue` is equivalent to `UIColor.systemBlue`.

Unfortunately, `Color` doesn't have a lots of `UIColor` system colors, hopefully Apple add missing colors on WWDC 2020.

May be use can use something like `Color.gray.opacity.opacity(0.25)` in the meanwhile?